# list length + string formatting + python

Tags: python, string

How would one change the string "Point" to be a variable input (string)?

```
result = []
list =  [[a,b,c,d][a,b,c,d]]

result.append( [["Point {}".format(i) for i in range(1, len(sub)+1)] for sub in list])
```

I basically dont want to use string "Point" as a constant but rather as another parameter value. I tried this:

```
result = []
list =  [[a,b,c,d][a,b,c,d]]
p_name = "Number"

result.append( [[p_name, {}.format(i) for i in range(1, len(sub)+1)] for sub in list])
```

I would like to end up with:

```
result = [[Number 1, Number 2, Number 3, Number 4][Number 1, Number 2, Number 3, Number 4]]
```

Thank you,

Comment: What is exactly your `Number 1`, a string, tuple, list?

Comment: @RubenBermudez String. I am using this to create a matching list to that of an input list, but so that it lists how many items there is in each list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result.append( [["{} {}".format(p_name, i) for i in range(1, len(sub)+1)] for sub in list])
```